# How to reverse engineer simple checksum

Tags: cypher, reverse-engineering, checksum

I have some hex data, of which I now the meaning (it's like time, location, ecc...):

```
01 64 00 00
01 01 01 2E
84 88 BE 00
00 AE 11 06
F8 03 C3 89
```

Followed by a checksum/cypher:

```
56 3B 87 9B
```

And another simple example (just the last bit is changing):

```
01 64 00 00
01 01 01 2E
84 88 BE 00
00 AE 11 06
F8 03 C3 88
```

With the following checksum/cypher:

```
DF 82 05 B3
```

And I have more of these examples.

Is there a way to figure out (reverse engineer) which checksum or cypher is used?
I have reasons to believe that it might be just a simple checksum or a simple cypher, nothing too fancy.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I found something, maybe...

I think that the hashing has been done using some crc method, and by using this very helpful tool:

https://reveng.sourceforge.io/readme.htm

I found these results:

```
width=32 poly=0x2882b989 init=0xc6ea9616 refin=false refout=false xorout=0x00000000 check=0x6d514c85 residue=0x000000000 name=(none)
```

Because this not being a standard CRC I don't know how to check if this polynomial works (I don't want to implement a CRC hash generator by myself)...

Is there any tool that can create a CRC hash given data input and polynomial's characteristics (like poly, init)?

I have found:

https://github.com/madler/crcany

but I don't know how to make it work (I didn't find any examples).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No.

Well, most checksum algorithms, even old ones, are designed exactly to prevent this. Change any one bit on the input, get a completely random looking checksum, that looks completely unrelated to every other possible checksum.

Of course you could run the different example inputs you have through all the algorithms you know and see if the output contains any of the example outputs (it could be at the beginning or the end, or maybe somewhere in the middle).

If it's any more sophisticated, it's probably using "[salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))". Adding a secret phrase (the "salt") to the data before running it through the algorithm. You could brute-force start guessing, but i hope you see this is getting very unrealistic very quickly.